# Test hive schema compatibility

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I want to test if changing datatype for a schema is compatible or not.
Eg:

```
df1=spark.createDataframe([],StringType())
df2=spark.createDataframe([],IntegerType())
```

I know if the two dfs are written as parquet, I can use mergeschema functionality to test if the two dfs read together are compatible or not

How can I find at dataframe/schema level if the schemas allow implicit conversion? Is it even possible?